# How to detect photo which was got from library or taken when use input tag

Tags: javascript

My feature is upload photo on mobile device browser include Photo Library or Take photo(not allow duplicate file same name).

Problem: Default name of photo taken by device is "image.jpg", so first photo uploaded, but second photo will be duplicated.
If i change name photo, i need to know photo that make by take photo because of if change all (include photo library and take) then check file same name is no effect)
Anybody ideas? thanks

[upload-file mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raXGM.png)

code

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">


var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
 var file = e.target.files[0];
 var nameFile = file.name; //
});
```

Comment: Why not change the name of the photo to image + a counter, that way you'd still know that it was taken by the device

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy var file = e.target.files[0]; i don't detect photo that make by take photo (the photo return can be Photo Library or Take photo (the image attached above))

Answer (score 1):

to my knowledge, you can't determine the origin of the file, whether it came drom the files system, camera, ...
But you could compare for example the `lastModified` and `size` properties of those two files to know if they are different. e.g.

```
var isANewFile = oldFile.lastModified + "-" + files[0].size !== files[0].lastModified + "-" + oldFile.size
```

the chances that two different files have the same size and were created exactly at the same time is pretty slim!

Comment: thank for your opinion. I think, i should do same this